# There is no data except for last hour in WSO2 EI Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm using `WSO2 EI 6.1.1`. I have followed the steps in [this article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Using+the+Analytics+Dashboard). But I can only see the statistics for the last hour, but not for last 24 hours, last 30 days, last year, nor any custom range.

[WSO2 EI Analytics for last hour and last 24 hours respcetively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMb1x.png)
[image: WSO2 EI Analytics for last hour and last 24 hours respcetively]

Comment: Provide more data, you are only providing link.

Comment: When did you set up analytics on your site?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Any errors in the analytics runtime console?